# restart problem after uninstall Ubuntu from Windows 7

Tags: grubrescue

I uninstalled Ubuntu from Windows 7 in stupidest way. I deleted the partition memory of Ubuntu from Windows. When i restarted my system it stuck into "***grub rescue***". how to solve this problem.? any advice. all my work are stuck into windows and i can't do anything now. pls help me.!

I'm new to Ubuntu and I don't know how it works. I don't want Ubuntu in my system.

Comment: Try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Try  2nd option in the above link.

Comment: I tried using boot repair. but when i restart, it says BOOTMGR is missing.

Comment: I got url as paste.ubuntu.com/7046005. and it still says **_BOOTMGR_** is missing

Comment: I fixed it. but boot-repair is general solution for this problem. but in my case, i need to change some other options in boot-repair. your advice really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Live CD with Ubuntu in it, an then you can Install [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Some Instructions are given in the Link **[HERE](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/05/reinstall-recover-grub-from-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd-usb/)**

To add boot-repair to the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

To Update your repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install boot-repair

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Once Installation complete run boot-repair on terminal by typing the following command or select it by System->Aministration->Boot Repair.

```
boot-repair
```